# transposing few columns to row in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Let's take the below dataframe as an example

```
+--------+-----------------------------
|id  | fee_amount   | discount_amount | 
|1   | 10.00        | 5.0             |
|2   | 20.0         | 3.0             |
```

I want to be able to convert the above dataframe to following

```
+--------+-----------------------------
|id  | amount_type  | discount_amount |
|1   | fee          |   10.0          |
|1   | discount     |   5.0           |
|2   | fee          |   20.0          |
|2   | discount     |   3.0           |
```

I just double the number of rows and I'm ok with that.

I only want one column where amount value is stored and another column where a type of amount is stored. In the above example, I am given names of columns i.e. `fee_amount`, `discount_amount` that needs to be transposed. Is this even possible to do in spark dataframe?

Comment: cool I didn't know about melt :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the solutions is to create an `array` with column `fee_amount` and `discount_amount` and `explode` (which will add a row)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df = Seq(
  (1, 10.00, 5.0),
  (2, 20.00, 3.0)
).toDF("id", "fee_amount", "discount_amount")

val result = df.select($"id", posexplode(array($"fee_amount", $"discount_amount")))

//Now replace the exploded value 0 with fee and 1 with discount
result.withColumn("amount_type", when($"pos" === 0, "fee").otherwise("discount"))
  .drop("pos")
  .withColumnRenamed("col", "discount_amount")
  .show()
```

Output:

```
+---+---------------+-----------+
|id |discount_amount|amount_type|
+---+---------------+-----------+
|1  |10.0           |fee        |
|1  |5.0            |discount   |
|2  |20.0           |fee        |
|2  |3.0            |discount   |
+---+---------------+-----------+
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How would this change if I have 10 other columns like id?

Comment: You can select the other column as well or join the original dataframe to get all other column.

Comment: can you give an example? I tried creating an array of columns and pass it to select method but it's complaining about expecting string/column as first argument.

Comment: yeah you can't pass an array you need to select as `($"id", $"col1", $"col2"...... , posexplode())`

Comment: oh that's a bummer. I wanted this piece of code to be generic enough. didn't wanna hardcode those columns.

Comment: Another way you can do is select the columns from original df and join it with `result` dataframe